# while loop that stops at predetermined mean

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop, mean

New to Python! I have a simple dataframe for tabulating quiz scores:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sam':[20,20,20,20,20], 'Jim': [20,20,20,20,15], 
'Stacy': [20,20,20,20,30], 'Leslie': [20,20,20,20,20], 'Jonathan': 
[20,20,20,20,15]})
```

Now, I want to write something that changes the top value of every column (starting at 0) until it's corresponding mean value is equal to something predetermined and then moves to the next column. It was easy enough to add a new row and do this by hand until I got the results I wanted (demonstrated below). However, I am looking for something that makes the program do the iteration I had to do in the iloc field in order to get the 'mean2' values which were predetermined. I imagine this would require a while-loop of some sort but can't figure out the syntax. Screenshot of final desired result below the code. Thank you!

```
df.loc['mean1'] = df.mean()
df.iloc[0:1,0:5] = 17, 17, 22, 22, 22
df.loc['mean2'] = df.iloc[:5,:].mean()
df
```

Screenshot of desired final dataframe. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but If I reformulate your problem:
What you want is to find for each particiant (column) the value of the first quiz score (df.loc[0]) that will ensure a participant to have an mean target score (mean2) ?

If it's the case you can do something like:

```
# a function that estimate the quiz value to have for obtaining mean score target
def estimate_replace(quiz_id, mean_target, participant_series):
    data = participant_series.loc[participant_series.index != quiz_id].values
    participant_series['mean1'] = participant_series.mean()
    participant_series['mean2'] = mean_target

    # Here is the key function!
    participant_series.loc[quiz_id] = mean_target*(len(data)+1) - data.sum()
    return participant_series

#mean2 : mean scores target per participant
mean_score_target = {'Jim':18.4,
                     'Jonathan':18.4,
                     'Leslie':20.4,
                     'Sam':20.4,
                     'Stacy':22.4}

#the quiz id to replace, 0 in your case
quiz_id = 0

df = df.apply(lambda x: estimate_replace(quiz_id,mean_score_target[x.name],x))
```

Notice that this code will works with any number of quiz values (rows) and that you can specify the quiz value to estimate/replace (`quiz_id`).

You will then get following output:

```
       Jim     Jonathan Leslie Sam   Stacy
0      17.0      17.0    22.0  22.0   22.0
1      20.0      20.0    20.0  20.0   20.0
2      20.0      20.0    20.0  20.0   20.0
3      20.0      20.0    20.0  20.0   20.0
4      15.0      15.0    20.0  20.0   30.0
mean1  19.0      19.0    20.0  20.0   22.0
mean2  18.4      18.4    20.4  20.4   22.4
```